# C++ : Writing doubles in a file with more precision than default

Tags: c++, file, double, portability, precision

I want to write doubles to a file but the string cast reduces the precision.
Edit : I don't really cast but put the doubles in an ostringstream.

Is there another way than parsing each digit using modulo and division to write the doubles with more precision  ?

Edit : My application needs to be portable

Here is my current code :

```
std::string arraytocsv(double v[], int size) {  
    std::ostringstream oss;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        oss << v[i] << ";";
    }
    oss << std::endl;
    return oss.str();
}
```

I've had the precision() function, it works. Thanks

Comment: What string cast? Doubles cannot be cast to strings.

Comment: How are you writing? Can you put some code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [precision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/) function.

Answer (score 4):

After declaring the string stream alter its behavior:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss.flags (std::ios::scientific);
oss.precision (std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1);
```

The first call, `oss.flags()`, forces C++ I/O to use scientific notation on this string stream, even on something like pi. Printing numbers smaller in magnitude than 1.0 in fixed notation will lose precision while printing big numbers in fixed notation is extreme overkill.

The second call, `oss.precision()` tells C++ I/O how many digits to print after the decimal point. Using digits10+1 tells it to print one superfluous digit; `digits10` tells how many digits the system is capable of representing without loss of precision.

You will need to #include  because of that `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`.

Answer (score 1):

Write it in binary. This is, by default, not portable (in that the serialized format is architecture dependent)

instead of

```
double myvalue = 123.4;
file << myvalue;
```

do

```
double myvalue = 123.4;
file.write((const char*) &myvalue, sizeof(myvalue));
```

Of course, this assumes that you don't require humans to read this (allthough, using UNIX tool like [`od`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/od) they might)

Comment: C++11 offers the `std::hexfloat` I/O manipulator. This reduces the architecture dependence to some extent. While different computers still do have different endiannesses, most have standardized on IEEE floating point to represent `float` and `double`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just working on one single system, you could write the actual binary data out to the file, that'll give you an exact copy. If you want to write to a text file, convert the binary to Base64 or something like that.

```
std::ofstream myfile("file.bin");
double x;

myfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));

// later

std::ifstream yourfile("file.bin");
double x;
myfile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x), sizeof(x));
```

Optionally, encode the bytestream as base64. If you want to store long doubles and you are going for base64-encoding, note that the long double is usually only 10 bytes, so you can ignore the padding that it usually gets when you serialize.

If you plan to exchange data between different platforms, but all of which use IEEE floats, you should probably be more careful and document the endianness of the file format. In that case, writing an ASCII string with base64-encoding would be more portable. To exchange data between platforms that do *not* all use the same binary float representation, you'd have to work even harder...